# Toast "The contact doesn't exist" shows up everytime I attempt to assign an image to owner account from User settings

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop

I'm using CM 12.1 SNAPSHOT. Yesterday, I wiped the data and when the phone booted up I finished the setup of accounts like Google, CyanogenMod and everything synced successfully. But the Owner pic in status bar doesn't load and when I try to assign it from Settings → Users, I get the message "The contact doesn't exist."

Also I made that in Google+ settings

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

So how to assign a picture to the owner account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two independent ways to set the Owner's picture:

1. Contacts
2. Dirty trick (requires root access)

For the former trick, launch **Contacts** app → tap **Set up my profile** under **All Contacts** and select a picture and a name. Fill other details (optional). That's it. The Owner pic is set.

After this point, even if you end up deleting the profile contact under **Contacts** app, the contact name and the picture you chose during profile contact setup would remain in existence and in effect.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

**The dirty trick:** The Owner pic is located inside the directory `/data/system/users/0/` named `photo.png`. The image location is mentioned in the file `0.xml` located at `/data/system/users/`.

Look for the string:

```
icon="/data/system/users/0/photo.png"
```

That's the key. You can  move your choice of image (not restricted to PNG filetype) under the data directory and update that said string accordingly. Android normally uses the PNG image with dimensions YxY for the user account pic.