# How to solve "The contact doesn't exist" problem on Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

I have a new Nextbook tablet that shows message "The contact doesn't exist" after tapping the user icon (top right of pull down menu). I am trying to change accounts, but I cant get to the user menu. I can access settings to see that I have two Google accounts on the tablet, but I can not access them from the user button to switch accounts.

To be more specific about the behavior when I tap the user icon: The screen flashes, click sound is heard and small message bubble shows with "The contact doesn't exist". The menu does not change to show users and add button.

Comment: There is a difference between user accounts and email accounts. The Gmail accounts are email accounts and you can only switch them if only an app (which wants to use those accounts) has such provision. User account on the other hand are similar to what you would see in your desktop OS. A completely different user space. So, what do you really want now?

Comment: As for the bubble, (it is called a toast), setup your profile in Contacts with an image to get rid of that toast. See [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124667/96277) for that

Comment: I understand the difference between users and accounts, but thought the information about the accounts might be helpful. I am trying to access the user menu. I can not add or change users because I can not access the menu. The account I am logged in on has a profile with image in contacts, but the toast still appears.

Comment: Tell us, do you see "Users"  under Settings app? If not, then your device doesn't support multi-user setup.  Confirm this by executing `adb shell pm get-max-users` . You would need [tag:adb] setup in PC. // I've tested this theory once. I deliberately made my device support only single user. In that case, whenever I touched that user icon in pull down menu, I received that toast.

Comment: That may be the problem. I do not have a "Users" option in settings. I will check this with PC later.

Comment: If I remember correctly, inside of Contacts you create a contact for yourself ans set it as your contact. I'm not putting it as an answer because I'm not 100% sure.